# Issue plotting a scatterplot with matplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to plot some figures inside a for loop from jupyter notebook:

```
for i in range(4):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['x'] = features[:, 0]
    df['y'] = features[:, 1]

    plt.plot(df["x"], df["y"])
    plt.show()
```

I got the following for the first figure. Do you know what is the problem please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pyplot.scatter()` for scatter graph and `pyplot.plot()` for line graph.